# Client specification in /etc/exports file

Tags: nfs

I want to share a directory in a nfs server to all machines in a particular subnet say (192.168.1.0/24). I was wondering if I could use both this notations in the /etc/export file?

```
    a)   (directorypath) 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(ro)
    b)   (directorypath) 192.168.1.0/24(ro)
```